# How to have multiple views in single window mode using GIMP?

Tags: gimp, icon, workflow

I'd like a real-time preview while editing icons in GIMP.

I know that you can press *View > New View* to get a real-time preview window, however in single window mode gimp puts the preview in a separate tab as if it was another image. This is obviously no good as now I have to go and click on the tab to see the preview, which would take longer than just zooming out.

I'd prefer to stay in single window mode, so is it possible to tell gimp to put the new view in a second window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You aren't the first to suggest this, but it isn't being worked on at the moment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622625

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the info. However this link is from 2011. Is there any more recent news? (I couldn't find anything)

Comment: No there are no more recent news. GIMP is an extremely, volunteer only, developer starved project, and having another image Window possible in single window mode, or image-area splitting is not in the works, or considered.

Comment: My advice is simply to put some effort and get used to multiple window mode: it can be more productive once you get to it.

Comment: This link is to GIMP's bug and feature request tracker. You can assume that the information there represents the current state, especially for features you can't find easily in current versions of GIMP. Even if the reports there have been created years ago.